# How to get Geographical coordinates by Google Map API?

Tags: google-maps

I have a list of cities and places, and I want to get their Geographical coordinates. 
Is there any api can do it?

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This process is called "Geocoding".  [Here's Google's API for this.](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#Geocoding)  There are also several other services that do this listed on [the "Geocoding" Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding#List_of_geocoding_web_services).

Answer (score 0):

Google has a limit on the number of requests you can make per day.  If you need a higher volume than Google allows, and you can live with lower quality data, you can try [USC WebGIS](https://webgis.usc.edu/).